# How to work with file paths in UriBuilder on linux

Tags: c#, linux, uri, .net-5

When running this simple program on linux it will throw exception `System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.`.

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var b = new UriBuilder("/path/to/file");
        Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
    }
}
```

If I try to pass Uri instead of string I'm getting `The format of the URI could not be determined.`

However on windows path like `"C:\\path\to\file"` can be parsed without a problem. How can I process such paths on linux?

Comment: It seems the problem is caused by the leading slash, but as this post says, https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/14590, the solution does not seem trivial.